# How can I make host-module project structure with Vue.js? (micro-frontend)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuex, vite, micro-frontend

**My original question:**
How can I set up a modular structure in a Vue.js based project? I want to set up a structure under a main/roof vue project (dashboard) where each module will be a different vue project and these modules will be displayed and opened in the main project interface. These modules will be independent of each other and gathered under a single core project. I want the main project to auto-bind these modules and folders. I think this is defined as multi-architecture or multi-modular structure, but when I researched, I found out that the structure I wanted to establish was a micro-frontend architecture. How can I implement this integration in its simplest form?

**Short questions linked to the original question:**

- What will the data interaction be like between main-module projects?
- According to which hierarchy will the folder structure be created?
- How will the module project be displayed in the layout of the main project?
- What should be used for the operations (webpack, vuex etc.) and how should functions be coded?

Here is a sample technical article that I used for the processes that I have created in my mind in this process: https://www.maxpou.fr/vue-js-module-architecture

I used routers in my experiments while trying to create and code this structure. I tried various directory scenarios on the folder structure. I tried creating sample components to use. But I couldn't find a solution where I could get close to what I wanted to do. The things I tried were ways that were logically far from what I wanted.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.